# Remove substring from string in ArrayList and put back into list - Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have code that works for this. But it is extremely disgusting in my opinion and needs cleaned up.

Here's the problem:
   I have an ArrayList with filenames in them and I'm trying to iterate over the ArrayList and remove the ending of filename.

Example:

`ArrayList<String> files` contains [`am.sunrise.ios.png`, `am.sunrise.ios@2x.png`, `am.sunrise.ios@3x.png`, `am.sunrise.ios~ipad.png`, `am.sunrise.ios~ipad@2x.png`]

In order to remove the ending components in the string I'm currently doing the following:

```
private static ArrayList<String> removeTrailingElements(ArrayList<String> IBImages) {
    for (int image = 0; image < IBImages.size(); image++) {
        if (IBImages.get(image).endsWith("~ipad.png"))
            IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).substring(0, IBImages.get(image).indexOf("~ipad.png")));
        if (IBImages.get(image).endsWith("~ipad@2x.png"))
            IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).substring(0, IBImages.get(image).indexOf("~ipad@2x.png")));
        if (IBImages.get(image).endsWith("@2x~ipad.png"))
            IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).substring(0, IBImages.get(image).indexOf("@2x~ipad.png")));
        if (IBImages.get(image).endsWith("@2x.png"))
            IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).substring(0, IBImages.get(image).indexOf("@2x.png")));
        if (IBImages.get(image).endsWith("@3x.png"))
            IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).substring(0, IBImages.get(image).indexOf("@3x.png")));
        if (IBImages.get(image).endsWith(".png"))
            IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).substring(0, IBImages.get(image).indexOf(".png")));
    }
    return IBImages;
}
```

Clearly is is some awful code. I'm looking to see if anyone has a cleaner way of getting the resultant ArrayList to contain [`am.sunrise.ios`, `am.sunrise.ios`, `am.sunrise.ios`, `am.sunrise.ios`, `am.sunrise.ios`].

I plan on converting the ArrayList to a Set (I believe Java has this ability, still new to Java) and then converting back to get rid of the duplicates in the list much like you would do in Python.

EDIT:
In the case anyone comes looking for such a solution, I found a one liner that worked for me (one liner in the for loop). It does the same thing as above and even puts it back in the ArrayList.

```
private static ArrayList<String> removeTrailingElements(ArrayList<String> IBImages) {
    for (int image = 0; image < IBImages.size(); image++) {
        IBImages.set(image, IBImages.get(image).split("~")[0].split("@")[0].split(".png")[0]);
    }
    return IBImages;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact criteria for removal? Anyting after `ios`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a finite list of file name endings that you want to get rid off at hand (such as in your example "~ipad.png", "@3x.png", etc.), I'd suggest you construct a regex from them (e.g., including "~", "@"), and then do a `String.split(regex)`. This gives you a `String[]` (String array), of which the value at index `0` will be the String you're after.

Alternatively, if you want to get rid of everything after a certain part of the String (e.g., "ios"), you can do a `String.split("ios")`. To get the "ios" part back into the result, you could simply concatenate: `String.split("ios")[0] + "ios"`.

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion and found a one liner solution! I appreciate the help!